# Почему 1 аргумент?

Tags: javascript

```js
var sum = function(person) { 
  arguments[0] = 'Аргумент [0]';
  arguments[1] = 'Аргумент [1]';
  arguments[2] = 'Аргумент [2]';
  console.log(arguments[0]);
  console.log(arguments[1]);
  console.log(arguments[2]);
  console.log(person);
  console.log(arguments.length);
}
sum('person');
```

почему кол-во аргументов выводит 1?

Comment: А что, по-вашему, он должен показывать?

Comment: Это не массив..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это псевдомассив, т. е. у него есть числовые ключи и свойство `length`.
Но всё же это не массив, который следит за своим `length`, поэтому это свойство проставляется один раз при создании.

Comment: понял, спасибо)

Comment: Спасибо тут выражаются через плюсы и, если какой-то ответ Вам помог решить вашу проблему, пожалуйста, примите его (галочка слева от ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Если есть необходимость, работать с псевдо-массивом arguments как с обычны "list array", то можно использовать методы прототипной связи конструктора Array с вызовом в конексте псевдо-массива.

```js
var sum = function(person){ 
/* 
   Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments,0, 1, 'Аргумент [0]', 'Аргумент [1]', 'Аргумент [2]');
*/
 Array.prototype.splice.apply(arguments, [0, 1].concat('Аргумент [0]', 'Аргумент [1]', 'Аргумент [2]'));
/*
  arguments[0] = 'Аргумент [0]';
  arguments[1] = 'Аргумент [1]';
  arguments[2] = 'Аргумент [2]';
*/
  console.log(arguments[0]);
  console.log(arguments[1]);
  console.log(arguments[2]);
  console.log(person);
  console.log(arguments.length);
}
sum('person');
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому-что [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) - это псевдо-массив, содержащий аргументы функции (зарезервированное слово)